# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\int_0^n \sqrt[4]{1+x^4}dx}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, contest-math

The following question is taken from [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxudHVtYXRoY29tcGV0aXRpb25zfGd4OjYzN2NiMDBlOWUyZWI2ZTU) question $1.$

> **Question**: Does the series 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\int_0^n \sqrt[4]{1+x^4}dx}$$
>   converge or diverge?

My attempt:

I tried to solve $\int_0^n \sqrt[4]{1+x^4}dx$ directly by using trigonometric substitution, however to no avail. The problem is due to the fourth root.

I have tried to key in $\int_0^n \sqrt[4]{1+x^4}dx$ into Wolfram Alpha by using specific $n,$ however weird numbers are displayed.

Some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : $\sqrt[4]{1+x^{4}}>x$.

Comment: Hints? Well, as @See-WooLee mentioned $$\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}>\sqrt[4]{x^4}=|x|\\\int_0^n\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}~dx>\int_0^nx~dx=\frac12n^2\\\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{\int_0^n\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}~dx}<\sum_{n\ge1}\frac2{n^2}=\dots$$

Comment: Looks legitimately tough.  I wouldn't try to evaluate the integral, because it looks hard (as you pointed out).  I would try to bound it instead and use some sort of Comparison Test.  The integral smells like it should be on the order of $n^2$, so I would bet on convergence.

Comment: Aaaaaaand, there you go.

Comment: I wouldn't evaluate the integral, you would get hypergeometric function.

Comment: Strict inequalities aren't necessary, as @Randall may have meant to mention. Indeed, the limit comparison test is enough, seeing as $\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}\sim_\infty x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course we have $\int_{0}^{n}\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}\,dx > \int_{0}^{n}x\,dx=\frac{n^2}{2}$, hence the given series is $<\frac{\pi^2}{3}\approx 3.29$.

Since $a>b>0$ implies $a^n-b^n> n(a-b)b^{n-1}$, by choosing $n=4, a=\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}$ and $b=x^{1/4}$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{n}\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}-x\,dx < \int_{0}^{n}\frac{dx}{4x^{3/4}}=n^{1/4}$$
so a lower bound for the given series is provided by
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\frac{n^2}{2}+n^{1/4}}\approx 1.68. $$

Comment: May I know why do we need $1.68?$ I thought it suffices to show that the series is bounded above by $\pi^2/3?$

Comment: @Idonknow: one does not need a lower bound to prove the convergence of a series with positive terms, of course, the second part only explains that is not difficult to achieve a lower bound too, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

We can establish a tighter upper bound by observing that $$f(x) = (1+x^4)^{1/4} \ge g(x)$$ for $$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & |x| < 1 \\ x, & |x| \ge 1. \end{cases}$$  This much should be obvious.  Then we have for any positive integer $n$, $$\int_{x=0}^n f(x) \, dx \ge \int_{x=0}^n g(x) \, dx = \frac{1+n^2}{2};$$ thus $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\int_{x=0}^n f(x) \, dx} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{1+n^2} = -1 + \pi \coth \pi \approx 2.15335.$$

Numeric evaluation gives the approximate value of the series as $2.0841476752128634$.